# Round with increments larger 1

Tags: r, rounding

How to round by increment larger than 1? Acctualy, I need the next "ceiling" in steps of 5. Example:

```
ceiling(c(2.5, 6, 9.9, 10, 11, 14, 15), inc = 5)   #not working
> 5  10  10  15  15  15  20
```

I tried `ceiling()`, `round()` and `signif()` but I could not figure it out. It's probably a repetition but my research always leads me to increments smaler than 1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh, just found, that it is working the same way as rounding to specific increments smaler 1 like: `x <- c(1,5,10) ; round(x/50, digits = 1)*50`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
a=c(2.5, 6, 9.9, 10, 11, 14, 15)
fiver=function(x)
{
  multiplier=floor(x/5)+1
  return(5*(multiplier))
}
```

> fiver(a)

[1]  5 10 10 15 15 15 20